# Using Forecasted Data to Augment Predictions

Tags: machine-learning, bias

We have a model that is predicting 5 year rent growth.  We know that supply for the next two years is at a record high.  We know that this record high supply is going to impact the rent growth prediction but because this is a model that predicts 5 years out, we are not able to introduce this supply knowledge into the training data nor the data that is used to generate predictions.

How can we account for this known event that we have record high supply for the next 2 years and know that this will have an impact on our 5 year predictions?

Comment: Imo, unknowns like this are best dealt with using simulations or expert systems based on historic ranges in supply and other relevant parameters from a model fitted to existing information. By generating thousands of possible scenarios from randomly varied parameters, more or less likely outcomes will be produced. Partition those scenarios into (for example) deciles, run averages for those groupings to see how the factors interact to describe or produce the outcomes. Normal distributions are often assumed for the parameter draws but if extreme values are possible, replace it with Cauchy

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is a panel data problem - given that building a model to forecast rental growth on both cross-sectional and time series data (i.e. data across several properties collected at varying periods in time).

In this regard, a distinction must be made between fixed and random effects, whereby **fixed effects** only consider factors that do not vary over time, e.g. land size, rooms per property. In other words, these factors are *time-invariant*.

On the other hand, **random effects** are time-dependent and will vary over time, e.g. interest rates, building costs, housing supply.

Notwithstanding that viewing the data would be necessary to advise further - one potential course of action is to model the predictions using a panel data model (as one example, the plm library in R allows for linear modelling across panel data).

The objective of this would be to estimate the effect on rental prices by considering only fixed effects at first, and then also estimating the same using random effects.

While this model makes it easier to isolate the time effect - attention must still be paid to the effects of confounding variables when doing so. e.g. if supply increases next year and interest rates fall concurrently - it can be difficult to know whether the increase in supply or the fall in interest rates had a larger impact on rental prices for that year.

Based on the information in the question - my view is that estimating these effects using a panel regression is a good first step.